# laplace transformations with limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the Laplace transform of $f(t) = 0, t < \pi$, $f = (t - \pi), t \in [\pi, 2 \pi]$ and $f = 0, t \ge 2$

I know the formula for the laplace transformation but somehow I am having trouble to get the right answer for this question

$$\int (t-\pi)e^{-st}dt$$ from $[\pi,2\pi]$ (that's how I set it up)

Help please

Comment: You need to post your question using Latex. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Do you mean $f = 0$ when $t \ge 2 \pi$?

Comment: f(t) is equal to all those the ones in brackets are the limits

Comment: But your domains don't make sense. You have $f = 0$ when $t \ge 2 \implies f = 0, t \in [2, \infty]$ but $[\pi, 2\pi] \subset [2, \infty]$ and $f = t - \pi$ when $t \in [\pi, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

$L{f(t)} = $$\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt\\
 \int_\pi^{2\pi} (t-\pi) e^{-st} dt$

Integration by parts

$-\frac {1}{s} (t-\pi) e^{-st}|_\pi^{2\pi} + \frac 1s \int_\pi^{2\pi} e^{-st} dt\\
-\frac {1}{s} (t-\pi) e^{-st} - \frac 1{s^2} e^{-st} |_\pi^{2\pi}\\
\frac 1{s^2} e^{-\pi s} - \frac {\pi}{s} e^{-2\pi s}   - \frac 1{s^2} e^{-2\pi s}
$

Comment: the ones with zero get ignore and only t-pi is being calculated right?

Comment: more or less.  I suppose I could have said: $\int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_0^\pi 0 dt  +\int_\pi^{2\pi} (t-\pi) e^{-st} dt + \int_{2\pi}^{\infty} 0 dt.$  Do you think that is more clear?

Comment: I thought since  t< pi it would be [pi, infinity]

Comment: alson when you did integration by parts did you multiply e by t and pi?

Comment: Multiply e and t by pi?  I am integrating with respect to $t$ and evaluating the integral at $\pi$ and $2\pi$